# They say, six-four

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual, letter-sequence

Without giving away anymore info other than this image below and that the sequence consists of 7 entries only, can you figure out what the correct answer is?

The answer is in the form _______ _______ (14 letters in total)

---

[image: Strings of letters, inside rectangles in a vertical line, from top to bottom: GEION, ASIION, ?, ERXON, EWXXON, ESLNT, INCIN]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The missing element is:

> AMVLN

Reasoning:

> Each element is of the form: (2 letters, Roman numeral, 2 letters). The Roman numeral is the denomination of a United States banknote: 1, 2, 5 (missing), 10, 20, 50, 100. The letters are the last two letters of the first and last name, respectively, of the person whose portrait appears on that banknote:
>
>  georGE I washingtON
>  thomAS II jeffersON
>  abrahAM V lincoLN
>  alexandER X hamiltON
>  andrEW XX jacksON
>  ulyssES L graNT
>  benjamIN C franklIN

So the requested answer is, I believe:

> ABRAHAM LINCOLN

Comment: Correct, well done!

Comment: @Jeremy Dover: What was the methodology for discovering the semantics of the seemingly random letters? Like a database of common puzzle datasets? It seems quite a big leap to imagine that the presidents names should be used instead of the myriad of other sequences one could imagine to try to match the characters.

Comment: @user000001 For me the break in was recognizing the Roman numerals.  The second step was noticing that those numbers were the proper numbers for the bills.  It does require some cultural knowledge.

Comment: How does the title connect to the answer?